# Как выгрузить из массива данные и вывести в виде таблицы

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть класс, которые содержит разные данные (числа и строки),
их количество может быть увеличено пользователем (сохранением результатов),
как их потом вывести в виде таблицы ?

```
       <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="594dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonCloseStat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Дата"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Баллы"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Оценка"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Уровень"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
```

Чтобы после нажатия кнопки создалось необходимое количество TableRow ?
Просьба сильно не пинать, только учусь.

Comment: а зачем вам таблица если тут можно использовать ListView или RecycleView?